# Are there scriptures that deal with refraining from procreating for the benefit of mankind to eliminate hereditary disease?

Tags: verse-identification, disease

Certain diseases gets passed through generations. One could argue the various references to generational curses where health problems are passed between generations could be linked to this.

Are there a reference that could be interpreted of being told not to procreate if so that the gene pool needs to be pure from non life threatening medical problems?

I am not talking about others making the decision for you but you yourself making the moral decision to not procreate.

Are there any scripture that would guide you if you have a hereditary disease and you know your children will suffer if you choose to have children

Comment: I am not clear as to what you are asking. Are you seeking for biblical support of the ideology of Eugenics ? [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics).

Comment: Yes. But not for strength or intelligence but just limited to purpose of eliminating hereditary disease

Comment: Whether for 'strength' or for 'purpose' the ideology of Eugenics is abhorrent in its very essence. You say 'eliminate hereditary disease' but, in practice, this means 'eliminate the _bearers_ of hereditary disease'.

Comment: That's the opposite what i was saying

Comment: Sorry but we don't allow questions asking for verses on a topic here.

Comment: Judging a person less worthy of existence based on the genetic pattern that God chose for them?  As @Lesley mentioned, illness (hereditary, accidental or contagious) is just part of the inheritance we received from Adam.  He uses our weaknesses and flaws as well as our strengths as part of His design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: Are there scriptures that deal with the evolutionary theme of refraining from procreating for the benefit of mankind?

Answer: No.

Biblical Explanation: The Bible explains why it is that humans get sick, become old and die.  This happens because after Adam and Eve disobeyed God sin entered into the world and, as a direct consequence, death was the result (Romans 5:12).  The ravages of sin and its consequences reverberate down to us today.  We inherit sin and the sin nature from Adam, and we suffer for it continually.  Instead of perfection came imperfection and humans have been deteriorating ever since.  All men die, all animals die, all plant life dies.  The world groans because of the consequences of human godlessness, selfishness and depravity (Romans 8:22).

Generational curses are mentioned in several places in the Bible.  Exodus 20:5 implies that rebellious children will choose to repeat the sins of their ungodly fathers and this, in turn, results in the consequences of those sins being visited upon future generations.  It is worth remembering that a generational curse was a consequence for a specific nation (Israel) for a specific sin (idolatry). The history books of the Old Testament (especially Judges) contain the record of this divine punishment meted out.  The cure for a generational curse has always been repentance. When Israel turned from idols to serve the living God, the “curse” was broken and God saved them (Judges 3:9, 15; 1 Samuel 12:10-11). Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/generational-curses.html

Conclusion: There is nothing in the Bible to suggest that humans should avoid procreation simply because they are not physically fit or because there is a risk of passing on a genetic predisposition that could result in sickness.  However, people have the right to decide whether or not to have children.  The Bible describes a time when God himself will intervene in the affairs of humans and He will wipe out all tears, sickness and death (Revelation 7:17; 21:4).

Comment: "_the Bible contradicts the idea that humans evolved_".  The original question isn't suggesting this.  It appears to be using "evolutionary theme" in the sense of what some call "micro-evolution", changes in the prevalence of existing genes.  For instance, if most people known to carry the cystic fibrosis gene refrain from reproducing, that gene will be almost eliminated from the human gene pool.  This answer doesn't refer to the creation/evolution again, and would be made better if that irrelevant first sentence were removed.

Comment: I'm afraid the expression "the evolutionary theme of refraining from procreating for the benefit of mankind" is not clear. It would be helpful if the question was edited to eliminate "evolutionary". Also, one of the tags is "evolution". However, I will make an edit.

Comment: “However, people have the right to decide whether or not to have children.” This statement in your conclusion is not discussed in the body of your answer. If this supports your answer to the question, can you please give a Biblical source?

Comment: The answer to my question is no, there is nothing in the Bible to support the notion that people should refrain from procreation “for the benefit of mankind.”  Neither is there anything in the Bible that says procreation is compulsory. That’s all.